# How to do a human infographic (waffle plot) considering decimal values? (e.g., have human icon with two colors)

Tags: r, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, waffle-chart

I have been strugglig with a waffle plot with human icon using R, where my data has decimal values.
(I based my code in this link: https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/create-infographics-with-r.html)
So, I want to plot 100 human, where 97.5 will be black and 2.5 will be blue.

For that, I do the following code:

```
waffle(
  c(`No-disease` =97.5, 
    `Disease` = 2.5), rows = 10, colors = c("black", "blue"),
  use_glyph = "female", glyph_size = 10 ,title = 'Percentage of disease', legend_pos="bottom"
)
```

I get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUgaU.png)

But my goal would be this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGVJB.png)

Thank's in advance.

Comment: As a proportion, 2.5 out of 100 is the same as 1 out of 40. Why not just make a 5 x 8 waffle, then a single person will be drawn in a different color, showing the proportion exactly?

Comment: Thank you, Allan, but this is just an example. I want to create several graphs with different proportions, so I would like to keep always the same size (100 icos).